# failing to install debian package

Tags: debian, checkinstall

I'm trying to install libdnet-1.12 Package for Snort and trying to get checkinstall to work. But it keeps saying:

```
Copying documentation directory... 
./
./INSTALL
./README
./THANKS
./TODO
./LICENSE
Copying files to the temporary directory...OK
Stripping ELF binaries and libraries...OK
Compressing man pages...OK
Building file list...OK
Building Debian package...OK
Installing Debian package... FAILED!
```

This is what's in the log file:

```
dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process /var/tmp/tmp.BI2nXpK3CZ/dpkginstall.log
```

Anyone know how I can fix this and get it to work? I can't find anything on what to do to fix this

Comment: possible duplicate of [dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process](http://askubuntu.com/questions/219545/dpkg-error-dpkg-status-database-is-locked-by-another-process)

Answer (score 0):

The dpkg database is locked by another process. The problem either dissolves by itself after some time, or you can see which process is blocking the database.

```
ps xa | grep apt
```

Close all software package manager and try it again. Or wait some time and kill the processes.

---

*Example*

```
$ ps xa | grep apt
 6088 ?        S      0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/synaptic-pkexec
 6090 ?        S      0:03 /usr/sbin/synaptic
```

Therefore

```
sudo kill 6090
```

Comment: Thank you, my problem was resolved, thanks for quick response