# Possible missing firmware for i915 and nouveau when updating kernel with ukuu

Tags: drivers, package-management, dpkg, lock

I am writing it as an experience as I found most of the answers are too detailed for a newbie and hoping that it will clarify two different aspects.

I was installing 5.3.4 kernel with UKUU and was getting lot of warnings on Ubuntu 18.04 which says

> Possible missing firmware for module i915

and same problem for nouveau. That is

> Possible missing firmware for module nouveau

On the top of it I got a problem which says your dpkg is used by some other application.

> error: dpkg is locked by another process
>
> error: dpkg status database is locked by another process

I found at [dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219545/dpkg-error-dpkg-status-database-is-locked-by-another-process) that it is inadvisable to remove lock files using commands like

> sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock

or

> sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend

or

> sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock

rather we should find the right process which is keeping the lock

maybe by using

> lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock

Actually, I do not remember by which command I got to know but I found that some unattended thing is actually kept the lock. But this was not shown anywhere in the lock files and when I was trying

> ps cax | grep PID

it was not helping me, as the grep command shows only those lines which are related to that PID, I dropped grep PID instead used

> ps cax | grep un*

This gave me right PID
I killed that process by

> sudo kill -9 PID

then I didn't removed any lock file just reconfigured the dpkg by

> sudo dpkg --configure -a

This helped me for my first part of the problem

Then I got to know that I have some problem with graphic drivers because of which I am getting

> Possible missing firmware for module i915

and same problem for nouveau. That is

> Possible missing firmware for module nouveau

I found that below link actually works for me without trying to understand much about graphic drivers and their details.

https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu/

My question related to lock file is -
What kind of locks are there in what all files they are listed and how the processes are divided to put their entry in lock files?
In my case I didn't get the PID in the lock files, (as I do not remember fully this part) is it possible that two PIDs are there related to same lock. What is such a case?

Comment: You do know that Ubuntu 19.10 will be released on Oct 17, and it's supposed to come with kernel 5.3. So why are you trying to install it yourself?

Comment: @heynnema Actually, I updated ubuntu back with apt-get update which resulted in issues of hanging frequently in which the only key that works is hard boot and wifi-adapter not found mo f the times. So some link suggested to move to better kernel with ukuu. 
After updating to this new kernel I am still facing a lot of issues. I really dont know what needs to be done and what could be better option.

Comment: If you still have it, can you boot back to the older/original kernel, and see if the firmware problems go away? Then we can troubleshoot your original problem.

Comment: I have tried 3 kernels a) 5.3.4-05034  b) 4.18.0-10 and c) 4.15.0-45
On a) and b) it is hanging with only left option is to power off but on c) the thing seems sluggish a few times, that is it seems hangs but after a while mouse starts movement with bit difficulty but then recovers good.

Comment: Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see if the system behaves normally.

Comment: Okay I will try that but wished to tell that even with 4.15.0-45 sometimes it says no wifi adapter after resuming from flap down.

Comment: Sorry, we had a three day power outage here. Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/fstab` and `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`. What happened when you booted from a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB? Did the wireless work?

Comment: I tried with live usb, it worked for sometime and after sometime it keeps on searching wifi network. But as of now I have reinstalled the system as it was hanging a lot. And unfortunately that also did not work. After installation when i booted the system, it does show a cursor only. On reinstalling I noticed that some "[Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata" is coming. And on researching I got "sudo apt-get install intel-microcode" but nothing worked

Comment: @heynnema I actually could not bear so much time, so I have gone for windows this time. Thanks a lot.