# Can't shut down due to "A stop job is running for Docker Application Container Engine" (endless counting / no limit)

Tags: upgrade, shutdown, docker

I tried to upgrade Ubuntu from 18.04 to 18.10, but there was an error with Docker. I tried to install it via the terminal, but it got stuck while "preparing to unpack".

I force-restarted the system and now I see a notification on the Software Update app offering me to download and install the latest update for Docker.ce, but the same thing happens - it gets stuck while "preparing to unpack".

Now every time I reboot/shutdown -- it just won't shut down due to

```
A stop job is running for Docker Application Container Engine (13min 58s / no limit)
```

I only wanted to upgrade the system, but it seems that I've done something wrong in the terminal.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What's your Kernel Version?

I have experienced the same problem with latest kernel in 18.04 (5.3.0-52-generic) and in 20.04 (5.4.0-30-generic).

I have a thinkpad T590.

Apparently switching to a different kernel version helps: 
See

- https://askubuntu.com/a/1236711/827401
- https://serverfault.com/questions/1015711/docker-ce-suddenly-broke-cannot-reinstall-hangs-in-systemd-service-enable

Comment: It's 5.3.0-52-generic

Comment: yes this + 5.4.0-30-generic have these issues with docker

Switching to 5.4.0-29-generic fixed it for me

Comment: Running `5.4.0-70-generic`  on `20.04` I experience the same issue

Comment: I don't have enough rep to answer your questions but I added `DefaultTimeoutStopSec=90s` to `/etc/systemd/system.conf` and it fixed for me.