# The causes for "dpkg status database is locked by another process"

Tags: package-management, dpkg, debian

In [dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219545/dpkg-error-dpkg-status-database-is-locked-by-another-process), I can know how to handle this error message.

And I also wonder the possible cause for this error. Does anyone have idea about it?

Comment: You've tagged this as being a Debian workflow or package creation issue?  Your question doesn't seem to relate to Debian-Ubuntu workflow or package creation & upstreaming?